# File uploading via google.script.run

Tags: google-apps-script

I was in the middle of refactoring code when this started happening.

When uploading a form via google.script.run that contains files ;

1) I noticed that the server was receiving something even when no file was attached.

2) The value of form[filefieldkey] always returnd "FileUpload"

3) When JSON.stringify(form[filefieldkey]) was applied for NO uploads the output was

```
{"type":"application/octet-stream","length":0,"contents":"","name":""}
```

4) When a file was uploaded, again form[filefieldkey] always returnd "FileUpload"

5) When a file was uploaded, JSON.stringify(form[filefieldkey]) actual values were substited into the json

```
{"type":"application/octet-stream","length":1000,"contents":"asf","name":"xx.txt"}
```

I honestly do not know what I did - that this behaviour is happening.

Any ideas please ?

### Update 1

JSON.stringify(form[filefieldkey]) - is short hand GAS server side code accessing the uploaded forms' fileupload field.

### Update 2

When actual files are uploaded, server side GAS does NOT receive a Blob, but a FileUpload as described above. I have to reconstruct the blob/file from the shove json object. Is this expected?

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Is this current expected behavior?

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand about your question because I cannot know about your script, about ``uploading a form via google.script.run that contains files``, if the content is sent to Google side by running ``google.script.run``, when the condition for running it is not set, ``google.script.run`` is run by both with and without the content. By the way, what is ``form[filefieldkey]``? If I misunderstood your question, I apologize.

Comment: Updated OP to explain my short hand code

Comment: Include [mre]. Your code and the error should be reproducible, if we were to load it in our accounts.